# Failing to extract content by xpath using HtmlUnit

Tags: xpath, htmlunit

I'm trying to extract the title from this Maltese news page

http://www.maltarightnow.com/Default.asp?module=news&at=Inawgurat+%26%23289%3Bnien+%26%23289%3Bdid+f%27Marsalforn&t=a&aid=99839603&cid=19

using the following XPath

`html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/h1`

(Ain't pretty but this Xpath was generated by Chrome and makes sense since there's a lack of element Ids).

I'm extracting the title programatically using [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) in Java. Here's the code. I've extracted news content and article date using the same code (obviously with a different xpath).

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = null;
        try {
            page = webClient.getPage("http://www.maltarightnow.com/?module=news&at=Inawgurat+%26%23289%3Bnien+%26%23289%3Bdid+f%27Marsalforn&t=a&aid=99839603&cid=19");
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
        }

        String text = ((DomElement)page.getFirstByXPath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/h1")).asText();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
```

However it's giving a null pointer for the mentioned xpath in

`((DomElement)page.getFirstByXPath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td/h1")).asText();`

The DomElement is not being found and I'm sure it's there, Chrome created the XPath after all.

What could be the cause of this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It is not that easy. You should:

1. See the text HTMLUnit is actually creating with `Page.asXml()`
2. Correct the XPath you're traversing to match whatever HTMLUnit is outputting in the previous step

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The Xpath which worked was actually /html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td/h1. At the end, instead of table[3] there's table/table[2]. No clue as to why Chrome gave me the first Xpath in the first place! Thanks again!